# Encapsulting an "include" so only selected classes are exposed

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope, information-hiding

**Question**: Is it possible to access a specific class from a header while hiding the other namespaces/classes defined in that header?

For example, say I have the header file -- *outcome.hpp*:

```
// outcome.hpp
namespace sports { namespace outcome {
  class Injury {};
  class Success {};
}}
```

In another header file -- *api.hpp* -- I wish to use `sports::outcome::Injury` without having `sports::outcome::Success` accessible to files that include *api.hpp*. Is that possible? If so, how can I achieve that?

P.S. In the actual code, *api.hpp* contains templated methods that would call methods of the `Injury` class so a forward declaration is not sufficient.

---

#### My attempts:

In my ignorance, I tried to achieve this by placing the `include` within an internal namespace. Here's a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
// api.hpp
namespace sports { namespace api {
  namespace internal {
    #include "outcome.hpp"  // I'm trying to hide symbols within this header
    using sports::outcome::Injury;
  } 

  class Boxing {
    private:
      internal::Injury sustained;
  };
}
```

I celebrated prematurely when that worked:

```
// This cpp file compiles file   \o/
#include "api.hpp"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  sports::api::Boxing b;  
  // sports::outcome not accessible
}
```

#### How it fails:

Things fall apart if a container from the standard library is used as a class member in *outcome.hpp*. For example, using this version:

```
// outcome.hpp
#include <vector>
namespace sports { namespace outcome {

  class Injury {
    private:
      std::vector x;
  };

// ...
}}
```

Compilation fails with the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ext/new_allocator.h:34:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++allocator.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/allocator.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/vector:62,
                 from outcome.hpp:1,
                 from api.hpp:5,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/new:93:54: error: ‘void* sports::api::internal::operator new(sports::api::internal::std::size_t)’ may not be declared within a namespace
/usr/include/c++/4.6/new:94:56: error: ‘void* sports::api::internal::operator new [](sports::api::internal::std::size_t)’ may not be declared within a namespace
/usr/include/c++/4.6/new:95:35: error: ‘void sports::api::internal::operator delete(void*)’ may not be declared within a namespace
/usr/include/c++/4.6/new:96:37: error: ‘void sports::api::internal::operator delete [](void*)’ may not be declared within a namespace
/usr/include/c++/4.6/new:97:62: error: ‘void* sports::api::internal::operator new(sports::api::internal::std::size_t, const sports::api::internal::std::nothrow_t&)’ may not be declared within a namespace
/usr/include/c++/4.6/new:98:64: error: ‘void* sports::api::internal::operator new [](sports::api::internal::std::size_t, const sports::api::internal::std::nothrow_t&)’ may not be declared within a namespace
/usr/include/c++/4.6/new:99:58: error: ‘void sports::api::internal::operator delete(void*, const sports::api::internal::std::nothrow_t&)’ may not be declared within a namespace
/usr/include/c++/4.6/new:100:60: error: ‘void sports::api::internal::operator delete [](void*, const sports::api::internal::std::nothrow_t&)’ may not be declared within a namespace
/usr/include/c++/4.6/new:103:57: error: ‘void* sports::api::internal::operator new(sports::api::internal::std::size_t, void*)’ may not be declared within a namespace
/usr/include/c++/4.6/new:104:59: error: ‘void* sports::api::internal::operator new [](sports::api::internal::std::size_t, void*)’ may not be declared within a namespace
/usr/include/c++/4.6/new:107:52: error: ‘void sports::api::internal::operator delete(void*, void*)’ may not be declared within a namespace
/usr/include/c++/4.6/new:108:52: error: ‘void sports::api::internal::operator delete [](void*, void*)’ may not be declared within a namespace
```

I'm obviously doing this wrong. Advice and a good telling off would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "exposing the namespace"?

Comment: Using the example above, I don't want `sports::outcome::*` to be accessible in files that include *api.hpp*.

Answer (score 1):

You can import a name from a namespace into a different namespace with a using declaration.

```
namespace sports {
  using sports::outcome::Injury;
};
```

In your example a lot of things are wrong. Especially the include is ill placed and you are lacking include guards.

```
// file1.h
#ifndef FILE1_h
#define FILE1_h

namespace sports { namespace outcome {
  class Injury;
}}
#endif

// api.h   
#ifndef API_H
#define API_H

#include <file1.h>

namespace sports {
  using sports::outcome::injury;
}

#endif
```

A file that includes `api.h` has now access to:

```
sports::injury x;
```

A file that just includes `file1.h` only has access to:

```
sports::outcome::injury x;
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to first include the header file that defines `Injury`, and would that not include everything within that header file? Pardon my ignorance, I'm still getting to terms with C++.

Comment: @ShawnChin Yes, you need to. I added an example. There is no way around including everything in that header. Try to separate your headers, have forward declarations, etc.

Comment: I left out include guards for the sake of brevity (they're there in the actual code). The ill-placed include was a lame attempt that hiding what's being included -- it certainly felt wrong, but I couldn't see how else to achieve that, hence the question.

Comment: @ShawnChin You cannot do that simply on the way the C++ include system works. It unfortunately has zero encapsulation.

Comment: Although it's interesting that my convoluted approach almost worked if not for the need to use containers from std.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intend correctly you want something like a 'private' or 'internal' namespace then? IMHO that's not possible in C++.

You might use a class to do this and place internal class definitions as nested classes there, your api namespace could be realized similarly exposing the other classes as public typedefs, provided that api is a friend of the internal class.

```
namespace sports
{
    class api;

    class outcome
    {
        friend class api;

        // Internal class definitions
        class Boxing
        {
        };
    };

    class api
    {
    public:
        typedef outcome::Boxing Boxing;
    }
}
```